# Не получается передать файл(картинка/видео) на сервер

Tags: javascript, php, файлы, formdata

Проблема заключается в том, что когда пытаюсь передать файл на сервер php, такие глобальные переменные как $_POST и $_FILES выводят не совсем то, что надо - например POST выводит только текст, а файлы же помечает как [Object File]. В общем, вот пример того кода, с помощью которого отправляю данные на сервер php:

```js
let dataForSendOnServer = new FormData();
  function onDropFiles(event) {
    dataForSendOnServer.append("newFiles", event.target.files); //добавляю файл-лист с дропзоны react
  },
  function addAdvestingPost(path) {
    if (path === "newNews" || path === "newAdv") {
      sendData();
    }
    async function sendData() { //асинхронная отправка данных через axios
      const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data[path]); //добавляю строковые значения из input'ов
      dataForSendOnServer.append("newData", jsonData);
      const url = "https://www.example/writeDataToJson.php";

      await axios
        .post(url, dataForSendOnServer, {
          headers: {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          console.log(response.status);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  },
```

**З.Ы.** отправку данных осуществляю без использования html-форм.
И принимаю на сервере выводом $_POST и $_FILES в ответ

```
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST);
```

Гуглил достаточно долго, но информации очень много, и часто ухожу не туда, куда надо.

Comment: В какой идиотской инструкции вы прочитали что надо делать json stringify файлам? И вообще, рекомендую читать документацию, а не рандомные советы из гугла. Например https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Порой из-за рандомных инструкций приходится тратить по нескольку дней на решение проблемы.. Проблему решил по вашему совету переписав всё так, как было в документации по formdata, спасибо